# A button is changing the text in a specific sequence, want another button to reverse the text

Tags: android, eclipse

My current code is below which is working fine and changing the information the way i want.

int _position = 0;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String[] answers = { "info 1", "info 2", "info 3", "info 4", "info 5" };
            if (_position < answers.length - 1) {
                _position++;
            }
            else {
                _position = 0;
            }
            answerLabel.setText(answers[_position]);

        }
});}}
```

THIS IS WORKING FINE

Button (Next) is pressed and the code above starts in action and when the other button is pressed at any time the text should start playing.

THIS PART NEEDS TO BE DONE

Now  i want to introduce another button which when pressed starts playing the information in the reverse.

Comment: Can you clearly state what your issue is? Its a little unclear what your issue is if its working fine and changing the info the way you want.

Comment: You need to implement the same in the your Next.onclicklistener with String[] answer reversed..I hope this is your problem. Anyway the question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should pull your String[] out of the function, so it stays static:

```
String[] answers = { "info 1", "info 2", "info 3", "info 4", "info 5" };
```

Then find the second button:

```
Button getAnswerButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Then add a second OnClickListener going in the opposite direction:

```
getAnswerButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (_position > 0) {
            _position--;
        }
        else {
            _position = answers.length - 1;
        }
        answerLabel.setText(answers[_position]);

    }
});
```